# Changing default zoom control in GEF editor (combobox) to slider

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I'm working on an Eclipse editor based on GEF.
I've added a zoom control for the editor, but I want it to look differently (specifically, I want it to be slider instead of a combobox).
Does anyone knows how can I do this?
Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, just override the

```
org.eclipse.gef.ui.actions.ZoomComboContributionItem.createControl(Composite)
```

to create a slider, and call

```
org.eclipse.gef.editparts.ZoomManager.setZoomAsText(String)
```

with correct parameters.